# VBScript Invalid Character 800A0408 compilation error, already tried ANSI, didn't work... Fix?

Tags: vbscript

I get a compilation error when I try to run the following vbs code from a command prompt in Windows 7 Vista. I've already Coverted it to ANSI but it still has the same problem

```
Set wshShell =wscript.CreateObject(“WScript.Shell”)
do
wscript.sleep 100
wshshell.sendkeys “{CAPSLOCK}”
wshshell.sendkeys “{NUMLOCK}”
wshshell.sendkeys “{SCROLLLOCK}”
loop
```

it says the issue is in Line 1 Char 36... Got Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This should works just give a try :

Because this **“** is diffrent from this **"** and this **”** diffrent from **"**

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
do
wscript.sleep 100
wshshell.sendkeys "{CAPSLOCK}"
wshshell.sendkeys "{NUMLOCK}"
wshshell.sendkeys "{SCROLLLOCK}"
loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You used Word as an editor, Word uses smart quotes. Autocorrect in Word changes " to opening and closing printers's quotes (ie 66 and 99).

Press Ctrl + Z to undo the change while typing or change options in Tools - Options - Autocorrect.

Answer (score 0):

similar premise as the other answers, but different solution - this can be as simple as changing encoding from UTF-8 to ANSI.
Open file in notepad,
go to save as,
change format to ANSI,
then save, and overwrite.

this has tripped me up LOADS of times before.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).